# Azure deployment fails because service not found

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-deployment

I am currently trying to deploy a cloud service to Windows Azure but I get the following error message:

`"Could not retrieve the list of cloud services.[...]"`

Details can be seen on the picture.

[image: Azure deployment fails]

It seems to me that VS couldn't find an existing service role in the subscription but my service is available and running, I just can not deploy a new version there.
A few days ago it worked correctly. Any Idea would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of Certificate generation, messing with azure toolkit, etc. I figured out that the problem was that somehow my computer tried to resolve the azure DNS to localhost because Fiddler got crazy and the proxy that Fiddler uses, haven't stopped even after restarting my computer.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem, when trying to deploy to azure while fiddler is running. Simply closing fiddler solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the previous screen, there will be an option of connecting to Azure using your credentials.  Select your subscription and you will be able to download a file to your local machine.  That file contains your subscription info as well as the keys.  Once you open that file through this wizard, you will be able to publish to your services.  You must create cloud services first before you do that.

Comment: Thank you, but after all, I had a proxy problem because of Fiddler.